# Calculate the boundary point of the cost of two curves

Tags: time-series, correlation

There is a function which indicates the cost per litre for a heat storage. When buying a larger storage tank, you get it at a lower price per litre. (left plot)

In addition, there is a function that indicates how the revenue of the system gets better with increasing size of the storage tank.(right plot)

[image] [image]

Is there a method to calculate which storage size is the most economical?

Comment: How do you relate cost/liter to revanue/liter?